# Nested If-Else in batch command

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, service, nested, errorlevel

I am trying to check if two services are present or not. If either one is not present it should print "No" else print "Yes". What I tried is:

```
@echo off
set service1=present_service
set service2=not_present

sc query %service1% | find "does not exist" >nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (
    sc query %service2% | find "does not exist" >nul
    if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (
      echo Yes
    ) else (
      echo No
    )    
) else (
echo No
)
```

If I check for the single one, it works fine. Here probably `%ERRORLEVEL%` is not changing its value in the second case. Even if `service2` is not present, it prints `Yes`. Can I get any help on this.

Comment: what do you mean by **Even if service2 is not present** ? Your code seems to work OK on my Windows machine.

Comment: I mean  service2 is not a valid service name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this;

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set service1=present_service
set service2=not_present

sc query %service1% | find "does not exist" >nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (
    sc query !service2! | find "does not exist" >nul
    if !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 1 (
      echo Yes
    ) else (
      echo No
    )    
) else (
echo No
)
```

This is a problem with [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: Tried this, but its executing the else part of first if condition.

Comment: Problem was multiple instances of cmd.exe were started. Works fine after killing them. Thanks , was looking for this since hours.

Comment: @iamsirjayesh it depends, variables inside parenthesis (`()`) use the `!`-version, because they need delayed expansion. However, the `%service%` variables don't really need it (although it's imo best practice), because they don't change inside the block.

Comment: @ Dennis ~ Thank You for the detailed explanation, will surely help me out in further steps. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to assemble an "AND" that query for more than one condition; this is a very simple method:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set service1=present_service
set service2=not_present

sc query %service1% | find "does not exist" >nul
set "bothServices=%ERRORLEVEL%"
sc query %service2% | find "does not exist" >nul
set "bothServices=%bothServices%%ERRORLEVEL%"

if %bothServices% EQU 11 (
   echo Yes
) else (
   echo No
)
```

This method also allows to test for more than 2 conditions without over-complicating the code...

Comment: Aacini: Much clear code, it  kind of concatenates each error level values. Thanks for the alternate solution, will definitely look in implementing it.